# How do a loop can help to center my data respect to a max value

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to design some code to iterate across my data and centre the values in respect to the maximum value of each column.

Here there is an example of what I'm trying to do:

INPUT

```
|  A   |   B  |       
|:-----| ----:|
|   4  |   3  |
|   5  |   2  |
|   9  |   4  |
|   8  |   7  |
|   4  |   5  |
|   3  |   3  | 
|   2  |   1  |
```

OUTPUT

```
|  A   |   B  |       
|:-----|-----:|
|   4  |   4  |
|   5  |   4  |
|   9  |   7  |
|   8  |   5  |
|   4  |   3  |
```

As proposed, I'm now using this piece of code that works perfectly fine for the example above. But it is still giving problems to my data. The error I get is:

> Error in (the_max - 4):(the_max + 4) : argument of length 0

Any help? I'm completely stuck

```
df_cent<-apply(df, 2, function(x) {
  the_max<-which.max(x == max(x))
  return(x[(the_max-4):(the_max+4)])
})
```

**Real Data**

```
dput(raw[1:20,1:5]) structure(list(Y0 = c(3145.126, 3178.701, 3224.385, 3304.599, 3427.954, 3564.216, 3663.065, 3607.685, 3416.442, 3213.872, 3082.273, 2967.31, 2914.054, 2902.385, 2879.799, 2863.839, 2845.718, 2833.797, 2811.662, 2778.558), Y1 = c(2678.572, 2647.732, 2624.185, 2617.655, 2589.248, 2559.836, 2520.349, 2484.969, 2469.404, 2472.38, 2486.179, 2495.08, 2505.582, 2524.076, 2526.301, 2536.212, 2514.524, 2470.91, 2425.193, 2407.115), Y2 = c(2782.993, 2801.221, 2849.327, 2887.829, 2862.908, 2882.687, 2926.137, 2910.612, 2928.439, 2942.857, 2949.042, 3007.03, 3025.96, 3028.522, 3019.542, 3006.743, 3020.229, 3023.875, 2985.96, 2944.298), Y3 = c(2451.421, 2454.053, 2448.346, 2430.966, 2425.783, 2429.053, 2416.686, 2393.618, 2378.365, 2356.911, 2371.982, 2381.778, 2385.626, 2378.868, 2363.729, 2352.621, 2349.481, 2374.857, 2374.877, 2354.132), Y4 = c(2350.779, 2361.946, 2354.645, 2339.802, 2257.112, 2230.763, 2235.095, 2212.157, 2200.369, 2199.146, 2162.409, 2147.56, 2118.352, 2111.032, 2122.665, 2111.456, 2082.912, 2071.944, 2075.322, 2068.664)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit further?  What is `centre the values in respect to the maximum value of each column`? why there two `4` in output of `B`?

Comment: Use `dput()` to share your data. From your table we cannot tell if you are working with a matrix or a data frame or something else. You can probably simplify your code considerably. For example `apply(x1, 2, which.max)` would give you the index numbers for the maximum value in each column.

Comment: Different columns correspond to a single analysis of different cells, each of them gives a concave curve, so I need to centre the data along the peaks (maximum value) in order to compare them. For the examples, I've just used random numbers. Once I've located the maximum using the for loop to detect the position of max values I'm just picking 50 rows above and below this value (top and bot vectors). What I need is a buckle that iterates through my data and does so.

Comment: this is my input class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 0):

an example for a vector:

```
x = sample(c(4,5,9,8,4))
x.ordered = sort(x)
middle = floor(length(x)/2)
below = x.ordered[1:middle]
above = rev(x.ordered[(middle+1):length(x)])
new.x = c(x.ordered[1:middle], rev(x.ordered[(middle+1):length(x)]))
```

to take the n values above or below the max:

```
above[1:n]
below[-n:-1]
```

The idea would be to detect where the middle position is and then used an ordered vector and its reverse (function `rev`)

Comment: I don't want to order my data, I just want to pick n values above and below the maximum value (keeping the input order!)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you could simplify this. Using `apply` on each column, determine the `max` and include values in the column +/- a designated width (in this example, 2 for `n_width`). Result is a matrix, but can be transformed if needed.

Note: if you have missing values `NA` in columns, make sure to include `na.rm = TRUE` when determining `max` value.

```
n_width <- 2

apply(df, 2, function(x) {
  the_max <- which.max(x == max(x, na.rm = T))
  if (the_max < n_width + 1) {
    return (c(rep(NA, n_width - the_max + 1),
              x[1:(the_max + n_width)]))
  } else {
    return(x[(the_max - n_width):(the_max + n_width)])
  }
})
```

**Output**

```
     A B
[1,] 4 2
[2,] 5 4
[3,] 9 7
[4,] 8 5
[5,] 4 3
```

**Edit**: With second data set, you will need `NA`s for situations when there are less than `n_width` observations before the maximum value. For example:

```
n_width <- 5
```

**Output**

```
            Y0       Y1       Y2       Y3       Y4
 [1,] 3178.701       NA 2928.439       NA       NA
 [2,] 3224.385       NA 2942.857       NA       NA
 [3,] 3304.599       NA 2949.042       NA       NA
 [4,] 3427.954       NA 3007.030       NA       NA
 [5,] 3564.216       NA 3025.960 2451.421 2350.779
 [6,] 3663.065 2678.572 3028.522 2454.053 2361.946
 [7,] 3607.685 2647.732 3019.542 2448.346 2354.645
 [8,] 3416.442 2624.185 3006.743 2430.966 2339.802
 [9,] 3213.872 2617.655 3020.229 2425.783 2257.112
[10,] 3082.273 2589.248 3023.875 2429.053 2230.763
[11,] 2967.310 2559.836 2985.960 2416.686 2235.095
```

**Data**

```
# First data set
df <- structure(list(A = c(4, 5, 9, 8, 4, 3, 2), B = c(3, 2, 4, 7, 
5, 3, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

# Second data set
df <- structure(list(Y0 = c(3145.126, 3178.701, 3224.385, 3304.599, 
3427.954, 3564.216, 3663.065, 3607.685, 3416.442, 3213.872, 3082.273, 
2967.31, 2914.054, 2902.385, 2879.799, 2863.839, 2845.718, 2833.797, 
2811.662, 2778.558), Y1 = c(2678.572, 2647.732, 2624.185, 2617.655, 
2589.248, 2559.836, 2520.349, 2484.969, 2469.404, 2472.38, 2486.179, 
2495.08, 2505.582, 2524.076, 2526.301, 2536.212, 2514.524, 2470.91, 
2425.193, 2407.115), Y2 = c(2782.993, 2801.221, 2849.327, 2887.829, 
2862.908, 2882.687, 2926.137, 2910.612, 2928.439, 2942.857, 2949.042, 
3007.03, 3025.96, 3028.522, 3019.542, 3006.743, 3020.229, 3023.875, 
2985.96, 2944.298), Y3 = c(2451.421, 2454.053, 2448.346, 2430.966, 
2425.783, 2429.053, 2416.686, 2393.618, 2378.365, 2356.911, 2371.982, 
2381.778, 2385.626, 2378.868, 2363.729, 2352.621, 2349.481, 2374.857, 
2374.877, 2354.132), Y4 = c(2350.779, 2361.946, 2354.645, 2339.802, 
2257.112, 2230.763, 2235.095, 2212.157, 2200.369, 2199.146, 2162.409, 
2147.56, 2118.352, 2111.032, 2122.665, 2111.456, 2082.912, 2071.944, 
2075.322, 2068.664)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It works perfectly for the example, but it is still not working for my real data. How should I adapt the margin in the apply function?

Comment: you have been really helpful. But I can not make it work. It still says that Error in (the_max + 4):(the_max - 4) : argument of length 0. I have concerns about the_max being not correct.

Comment: It works perfectly for the example but not for my data. I'm importing an excel table using R studio interface and then I convert it to a data frame using df2<-as.data.frame(df1). The problem must be here.

Comment: I've solved it!!!! The columns of the input were of different length (completed with NA values). Input data should not have NA values. Thanks a looooooot! @Ben

Comment: @ClaudiaSalat Glad to hear! If you have missing values, you could try adding `na.rm = T` to `max`.